# Navigate between routes/components of different modules with their own routing modules in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, router

My application has a lot of different modules with their own routing modules. So let's say in module "A" I have a component which must have a router link in its a template that must lead to module B component(module B has its own routing module).
AppRouting module( which has a wildcard and a few other components) is imported last in App module and module A and B  before that as per Angular documentation.
But still routerLink directive doesn't lead to module B component.

What else must be done, so that I can use router link directive in a template of the component in module A to direct to the component in module B???

Comment: have you made any progress regarding this?

Comment: No, still not working. Not sure that it is going to work like that, I think some trick should be applied there.

Comment: adding the relevant code could help us debug this easier

Comment: I restarted the machine, cleaned the browser, didn't help, then run deleted npm modules, installed again and run npm audit fix cause there were about 20 red issues. And after all that  routing started to work.